# Python 3 mySQL.connector frozen import lib

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to Python 3 and still learning but I need help.  The first part of the script is:

`import mysql.connector #this is failing as a .py but works in the shell`

`cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='mypassword', host='my_ip_address', database'name_of_database') #this works in the shell`

`cursor = cnx.cursor()`

I have tried the above line by line in the Python shell which works fine: I can import the connector to connect to my database and fetch back data.  But when I save the script as a .py the `import mysql` connector does not work. I do have the Path variable setup and when I installed the mySQL connector it placed the relevant files in my Python install path \Lib\site-pacakges folder.

I get the following error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1518, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\scripts\mysql.py", line 2, in <module>
>    import mysql.connector
>  File "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\scripts\mysql.py", line 2, in <module>
>    import mysql.connector
>ImportError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; mysql is not a package
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the same question as your, and I found an answer in another website where you asked the same question. I'm pasting the answer here as reference.

> The above happens because your script is named 'mysql.py', which is
>   actually the same name as the 'mysql' package. Python correctly
>   reports ImportError. Simply rename your 'mysql.py' to something else,
>   like 'mysqlhacks.py'.

Taken from https://answers.launchpad.net/myconnpy/+question/226992